Angular Acceleration of a rigid body about different axes

Angular acceleration of a rigid body about any axis is the same.

Is this statement true? If yes, then why? If not, then what's the mistake in this?
PS:I know there are similar questions already asked but somehow they are addressing a different query and they aren't satisfactory
Edit: Just to clarify, the problem statement is

WHY IS THE ANGULAR ACCELERATION ABOUT A RIGID BODY INDEPENDENT OF THE CHOICE OF THE AXIS (i.e. The Angular Acceleration is same for any axis).


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


the velocity at Point P
$$\vec v_P=\vec v_1+\vec\omega_1\times \vec r_1=\vec v_2+\vec\omega_2\times \vec r_2\tag 1 $$
with
$$\vec v_2=\vec v_1+\vec\omega_1\times \vec r=\vec v_1+\vec\omega_1\times (\vec r_1-\vec r_2) $$
substitute $~\vec v_2~$ into equation (1) , you obtain
$$~(\vec\omega_1-\vec\omega_2)\times \vec r_2=0$$
and because $~\vec r_2 ~$ is arbitrary thus $~\vec\omega_1=\vec\omega_2~$
form here
$$\dot{\vec{\omega_1}}=\dot{\vec{\omega_2}}$$

Angular acceleration of a rigid body about any any  point is the same

Here is a clarification of the problem:

$O$ is the origin of the reference frame (the lab frame).
$O_1$ and $O_2$ are two points on a rigid body, and they have velocities $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ relative to $O$, respectively.
There are two angular velocities, $\vec{\omega}_1$ relative to $O_1$ and $\vec{\omega}_2$ relative to $O_2$.


could you please clarify what are v1,v2,w1 w2,O1,O2
also please specify how did you get the second equation

@AtharvaThakur I put more Information

It's no mistake.
The angular velocity and angular acceleration is the same for all points about any axis of rotation on a rigid body. The following is a physical explanation:
Consider angular velocity. For the rotating rigid body where the position of every point relative to every other point is fixed, every point on the body must complete one revolution in the same amount of time. The difference is the tangential velocity of the various points will be different for different points for a given axis of rotation. For each axis of rotation the tangential velocity of points furthest from the center of rotation must be greater in order to cover a greater distance in the same time.
FIG 1 below shows two arbitrary fixed points on a circle rotating about its geometric center which is then the center of rotation (COR). FIG 2 shows the same two points with a different COR. For both COR the two points complete one revolution ($2\pi$ radians) in the same time, which means the angular velocities are identical for both points for both COR.
Since angular acceleration is the rate of change in angular velocity, and the angular velocity is the same for all points, angular acceleration must also be the same for all points.
Hope this helps



This argues that angular velocity and acceleration for any point about a given axis is the same for all points.  The question is why is it the same independent of what axis you choose to measure around.  @Eli addresses that.

@Malcolm I gave a physical explanation. Since all points on a rigid body are fixed with respect to one another, all points must complete a revolution ($2\pi$radians) at the same time, thus angular velocity (rad/s) must be the same for all points. From that it follows that angular acceleration, the rate of change of angular velocity, must also be the same for all points.

@BobD your are answering to a different problem.
Im asking why is the angular acceleration of a rigid body about ANY AXIS is same(i.e. it has a same value for all the axes)
You're answeing to:
Why is the angular acceleration of all points about an axis is same

@AtharvaThakur My answer applies to all points about any axis. The only thing that changes for different axes of rotation is the tangential velocities of the different points. I've updated my answer to clarify this. I am also attempting to develop figures to show this.
